# Get Results from table if value are present in multiple

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have this table:

| affiliate_id | parent_affiliate_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 12 | 11 |

What I need is to make a query that shows all parents of an affiliate.

Expected outcome:

| affiliate_id | all_parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 3, 4, 5 |
| 2 | 3, 4, 5 |
| 3 | 4, 5 |
| ... | ... |
| 10 | 9 |
| 12 | 11 |

I'm trying to use this query but without success:

```
$aff = 1;
foreach( $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT A.*
 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table A
 JOIN 
  ( SELECT affiliate_id
       , parent_affiliate_id
       FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table
       WHERE $aff IN(affiliate_id, parent_affiliate_id) 
        ) B
 ON A.affiliate_id = B.affiliate_id 
 AND A.parent_affiliate_id = B.parent_affiliate_id
 " ) as $key => $row) {
$subaff1 =  $row->parent_affiliate_id;
 echo 'Affiliate Id: '. $aff; echo ' - Parent: '. $subaff1; echo     '<br/>';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED

Maybe i solved in part
using this code

```
SELECT affiliate_id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( parent_affiliate_id) from affiliates B where B.affiliate_id BETWEEN A.affiliate_id AND B.parent_affiliate_id) AS all_parent_id FROM affiliates A
```

Show me all parents of every affiliate id
but i need to show too the parent of an affiliate
that have only one parent

You can test it here
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dKBfxUpb8fBXLTQqRKbN2B/1

Comment: Thanks @brombeer for added the tag. You cannot help me?

Comment: You could make it more clearly by showing the expected outcome for your query in tabular way

Comment: Hi @LuisVenezian, the result of the query i need are.  In my case id of affiliate 1. I need to show all parent connected to affiliate with id 1 : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
As you see 1 are affiliate id and 2 are parent id but 2 are same affiliate id and have 3 like parent and 3 have 4 like parent and 4 have 5 like parent, so all are connected.

Comment: your SQL query works on this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WRvcMBwbwCJhTtpX9rt4v/0, have you enabled WP DEBUG LOG to check if anything is being thrown?

Comment: Hi @Phil, my query work bug give me only one result. 
I need to have a list of all parent of affiliate with id 1.
So i need to have a result like : 2,3,4,5 but my result are only 2.

Comment: instead of SELECT A.* use SELECT A.affiliate_id

Comment: your code also get the parent of your targetted affiliate but this will be ambiguous in the returned values

Comment: Sorry @Phil maybe i dont understend good. I dont need only the parent associated to affiliate id 1 but all parent of 1, becouse 1 have 2 like parent but 2 have 3 like parent and 3 have 4 and 4 have 5. I need the list of parent connected to 1 in my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` and a subquery like the following:

```
SELECT affiliate_id, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(affiliate_id) from affiliates B where B.parent_affiliate_id = A.affiliate_id) AS all_parent_id 
FROM affiliates A
```

You can test it here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WRvcMBwbwCJhTtpX9rt4v/2

[Here you can find more information.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/) Keep it simple.

Comment: Sorry @Lvcios, but your code are not wat i want. 
Read good my post, i need to show the connection from affiliate 1
Affiliate 1 have parent 2 and 2 have parent 3 and 3 have parent 4 and 4 have parent 5.
So affiliate 1 are connected to all of this.
I need this kind of output if i ask for affiliate 1.

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved by means of recursive Common Table Expressions if available (MySQL 8.0, MariaDB starting with 10.2.2) as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE affiliate_relation (affiliate_id, all_parent_ids) AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT(a_p.parent_affiliate_id),
    CAST('' AS CHAR(20))
  FROM
    affiliate AS a_p
    LEFT JOIN affiliate AS a_c
      ON a_p.parent_affiliate_id = a_c.affiliate_id
  WHERE
    a_c.affiliate_id IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT
    a.affiliate_id,
    IF (
      a_r.all_parent_ids = '',
      a.parent_affiliate_id,
      CONCAT(a.parent_affiliate_id, ',', a_r.all_parent_ids)
    )
  FROM
    affiliate AS a
    JOIN affiliate_relation AS a_r
      ON a.parent_affiliate_id = a_r.affiliate_id
)
SELECT
  affiliate_id,
  all_parent_ids
FROM
  affiliate_relation
WHERE
  all_parent_ids != ''
ORDER BY
  affiliate_id
```

It could be tested here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h18jBgh2322J6fj5XRofKu/1